# importNode throws org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxon

I am trying to merge two XML documents both with standard Oracle JDK 7 and also with Saxon HE but I keep getting an:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: The implementation does not support the requested type of object or operation.`
```

On the line with the `importNode` below (same thing happens with `adoptNode` BTW):

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class FooMain {

    private static Document slurp(String s) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Document doc  = slurp("<a></a>");
        Document doc2 = slurp("<b></b>");
        Node not_used = doc.importNode(doc2, true);
    }
}
```

I've tried both with `Saxon-HE-9.4.jar` on my classpath or not, but I still get the same error.

## update

Based on comments I received, when I try with:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl", null);
```

I get instead:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Saxon DOM implementation cannot be updated
  at net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeOverNodeInfo.disallowUpdate(NodeOverNodeInfo.java:719)
  at net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentOverNodeInfo.importNode(DocumentOverNodeInfo.java:211)
  at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:16)
```

After googling I see [old messages](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cocoon-users/200408.mbox/%3C00a101c477a5%24a12a4e30%24111ee204@dallas.sil.org%3E) to the effect that Saxon apparently creates a read-only DOM which is weird since I thought that one of the comparison points of DOM vs SAX is that DOM is read-write whereas SAX is read-only.

Comment: First find out which DOM implementation you are actually using (look at what factory is returned.) Recent releases of Saxon do not provide a DocumentBuilderFactory that will be detected by the classpath search, since the DOM classes in Saxon are provided only as a wrapper interface for Saxon's internal tree structure.

Comment: @MichaelKay `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().getClass().getName()` gives `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`. So how do I ensure that the Saxon DOM implementation is used instead?

Comment: You need to tell the document builder which factory to use.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: Saxon's DOM implementation is there only to provide a DOM API to the results of a query or transformation. It's not designed to allow you to create a DOM programmatically. If you want to do that, use Xerces. On the other hand, to perform your desired task of merging two documetns using Saxon, you don't want to be using a DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two documents (I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this, but I'll guess) using Saxon, you don't want to be fiddling about with a DOM. Just run this XQuery:

```
<doc>{doc('a.xml'), doc('b.xml')}</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
Node node = doc.importNode(doc2.getDocumentElement(), true);
```